# Core Data's NSPersistentContainer in iOS 10 / macOS Sierra

Tags: ios, core-data, containers, wwdc, viewcontext

I am **really** excited to use Core Data now because of how much *simpler* they made it (as of WWDC 2016).

On app launch, I plan to load pre-updated data from Core Data and then have the `persistentContainer`'s `performBackgroundTask` do updates/saves to some entities. As entities are updated in the background, the UI should always show the most **recent** data when fetching (whether those entities were updated or not).

When I'm working with ONE context, is it safe to both set the viewContext's `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` flag to `true` AND its generation to `.current`?

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container: NSPersistentContainer = {
        $0.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        try? $0.viewContext.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)
        return $0
    }(NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyFirstApp"))

    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error._userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

Both those settings should be fine, but if you're only working with one context, neither will matter.  `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` will only merge changes when a different context performs a save and query generations are useful when another context is changing data that your current context is reading.